# Try flutter interface to send an image to an API to convert it to .svg format on localhost

Tags: flutter, dart

I am testing to create an application in Flutter to send an image to an API to convert it to .svg, but I have doubts if I am sending the image properly.

Looking for documentation, and implemented sending the image as "Multipart", taking into account that it is the appropriate way for the API to process it. The API is created in fastapi.

```
#Code Flutter

 Future uploadImage() async {
    if (_image == null) return;
    String apiUrl = 'http://localhost/convert';
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(apiUrl))
      ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', _image!.path));

    try {
      var streamedResponse = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          _imageUrl = jsonResponse['url'];
        });
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error al convertir la imagen');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

#Code api

    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    input_dir = "input_images"
    output_dir = "output_images"
    
    
    os.makedirs(input_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    @app.post("/convert/")
    async def convert_image(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
        if file.content_type not in ["image/jpg", "image/png"]:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Archivo no soportado. Solo se aceptan imágenes JPEG o PNG.")
    
        filename = os.path.basename(file.filename)
        input_path = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
        output_filename = f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}.svg"
        output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)
    
    
    }
```

Comment: place print statement in the api code to check weather you are getting image or not. BTW the code looks fine